# Unwanted spaces between characters on UIButton title text in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, alignment

Code for **UIButton**

```
btnChooseHour.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
btnChooseHour.clipsToBounds = YES;
btnChooseHour.layer.borderColor = [CustomUIControls getConstantCustomColor:COLOR_67].CGColor; //Custom Color
btnChooseHour.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;

[btnChooseHour.titleLabel setFont:FONT_AWESOME_(13)]; //Custom Font
[btnChooseHour.titleLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.8];
[btnChooseHour setTitleColor:[CustomUIControls getConstantCustomColor:COLOR_153] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //Custom Color

[btnChooseHour setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t%@", strDisplayDate, [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAIconCaretDown]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Setting Title
btnChooseHour.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

[image: Screen_Shot]

In **iOS 7** and newer version, it is displaying perfectly. But while using in **iOS 6**, Button's title has some unwanted spacing between every characters.

How to remove spacings between title text of **UIButton** specially in **iOS 6**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't see any issues here, could you post a screenshot for iOS 7 as well